# When are you going/ when do you leave

Tags: dates

How to ask when exactly (date) someone is leaving?
My friend is traveling to America next week and I'm not sure how to ask about date.

> When do you leave
>   When are you going
>   When you will be leaving

Which ones are correct?

Comment: Change the third example to: When will you be leaving? and throw in questions marks - and you can take your choice.

Answer (score 2):

> When do you leave?
>   When are you leaving?

I would interpret this as a question about flight (or ferry/boat) times, or as a question about which day the flight would be on. I would expect a specific answer, such as the day or an approximate time on a day.

> **When do you leave?**
>
> Our flight is at 4 AM.
>   We leave on Friday.

---

> When are you going?

I would expect this question only to be asked if the trip was not in the near future, and I would only expect a general answer – a season, month, or week.

> **When are you going?**
>   *(or: When do you go?)*
>
> The trip is in June.
>   We're going next spring.
>   We leave the second week of September.

Answer (score 1):

As Ronald Sole mentions in his comment, the third question should be "When will you be leaving?" but otherwise all three are perfectly fine.  Other examples:

> When are you going to be leaving?
>
> When are you going to leave?
>
> When do you depart?
>
> When are you going to depart?

As well as many others.